# Dynamically added element's directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple infinite scroll. It loads the data fine but after loading, new added elements' directives don't work.

This is relevant part of the scroll checking and data loading directive.

```
.directive("scrollCheck", function ($window, $http) {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {           
                // calculating windowBottom and docHeight here then
                if (windowBottom >= (docHeight - 100)) {
                    // doing some work here then            
                    $http.get('service page').then(function (result) {
                        if (result.data.trim() != "") {
                            var newDiv = angular.element(result.data);  
                            element.append(newDiv);                                                             
                        } 
                        // doing some other work
                    },function () {
                        // error handling here
                    });                                 
                }                    
                scope.$apply();
          });
     };
})
```

Service page returns some repeats of this structure as `result.data`

```
<div ...>
    <div ... ng-click="test($event)"></div>
    <div ...>...</div>
</div>
```

As i said data loads just fine but those `test()` functions in `ng-click`directives don't work. How to get em work?

Comment: You need to `$compile(newDiv)(scope)` - essentially compile/link against some `scope`... but unless you are truly getting dynamic HTML, you should be getting the data itself, and then just add to some repeater of some template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are going to need to compile the html element returned. Something like this

```
         $compile(newDiv)(scope);  // Corrected. Thanks
```

You'll need to be sure and pass in $compile into your function