# How to make a dynamically added element's ng-show directive apply

Tags: angularjs

First off, I know angularjs is not meant to be used this way but I use it this way anyways :)

Secondly, i just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063456/dynamically-added-elements-directive-doesnt-work) and got it answered 2 days ago but it doesn't apply for ng-show directive.

Got a list and a set of divs that has ng-show directive each which is hiding em if some value is not equal to list's value. This all hard-coded by the way - again i know i'm not supposed to use angularjs for this

```
<select ng-model="selected_album">
    <option value="1">Album 1</option>
    <option value="2">Album 2</option>
    ....

<div ng-show="selected_album == 1">.....
<div ng-show="selected_album == 1">.....
<div ng-show="selected_album == 1">.....
<div ng-show="selected_album == 2">.....
.....
```

Got a js function that uploads images and then adds to DOM inside in its own div with specific `ng-show="selected_album == CURRENT_SELECTED_INDEX"` directive like

```
$scope.upload = function(files){
    .....
    // after upload progress below is the part that creates and adds the div
    var div_new = document.createElement("div");
    div_new.className = "overlay_thumb";
    div_new.setAttribute("ng-show", ("selected_album == " + selected_index));
    div_new.innerHTML = 'stuff';
    div_some.parentNode.insertBefore(div_new, div_some.nextSibling);
    $compile(div_new)($scope);
    // there is no fail until here. div is being added to DOM just fine
    // but angularjs is adding ng-shide to it directly i dont know why so
    // i wrote this to remove ng-hide from it
    $timeout(function(){ div_new.classList.remove("ng-hide"); },200);
    ....
}
```

Even `ng-click` directives of the elements inside that new div are working but not `ng-show` for the div. How to make it work?

Comment: `but I use it this way anyways`  ...  why? You are making things so much harder and writing a whole bunch of unnecessary code when all you need to do is change a scope variable to do what you need in this instance. Now you are wasting efforts with getting compile to work. Proper solution is toggling a single boolean on the scope

Comment: @charlietfl yes i know if i would have put that divs in a repeater and make them pop themselves up with some data then all i need would be just to add some value to the data object but what if i really need to add an element which is irrelevant from that data but relevant to that selection anyways? I know that sound odd but what i'm asking is if there is a way to do that

Comment: But how can it be irrelevant to the data... the data drives the view. You are looking at angular all backwards.  Don't think about the DOM first. Think about how you can modify the data model and then how that change in model can reflect in the view

Comment: So if you need to add another element...then use `ng-repeat` ... create a scope array, and push a new object into that array. Then angular will create the DOM element for you